# Woocommerce Custom Shipping API

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, shipping-method

I would like to integrate a custom shipping method API into Woocommerce. Documentation is saying that I need to use a method POST and to parse a JSON to a third party logistic company. I tried to test an API with a Postman and the request was send successfully. But I do not understand where to send the request and integrate API request. Could someone please help me with a suggestion or an example? Thank you in advance

I tried make a custom shipping api plugin according to Woo documentation but I do not understand where to send a request and integrate API request

Comment: Here you go - https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#shipping-methods

Comment: I believe you have to get the necessary parameters from your order in WooCommerce and then pass it to the third-party API. You need to use the [wp_remote_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/) function.